# blade condition for laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

i want to create a condition inside a foreach that when no information is found in the database to display a message, but when it does not find anything infos is not displayed.
Can someone explain to me where i'm wrong? please

Controller:

```
public function mycharacters()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $user = Player::where('account_id', $id)->get();

        return view('user.characters')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

Blade

```
                <h1 class="text-light">My Characters</h1>
                @foreach ($user as $u)

                @if ($u->name !== "")
                <h1 class="text-light">{{ $u->name }}</h1>
                @else
                <h1 class="text-light">I have not found anything!</h1>
                @endif

                @endforeach
```

Comment: in all cases it would be better to do this `$user = Player::where('account_id', $ id)->first();` so select will pull only one element. and you don't have to manage an array

Comment: second it would be better to write `<h1 class="text-light"> {{ $u->name != null && $u->name!="" ? $u->name : "I have not found anything!" }}</h1>`

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia i need an array, but the problem was solved with the help of Luke :d
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're expecting `$user` to be empty, so then the foreach has nothing to loop through.

Instead you should either loop through the users or show a message when empty

```
@forelse ($user as $u)
    <h1 class="text-light">{{ $u->name }}</h1>
@empty
    <h1 class="text-light">I have not found anything!</h1>
@endforelse
```

The `@empty` block will render in cases when the variable being looped over is empty.

Comment: Super, it looks like it worked, i really didn't know about **@forelse** and **empty**
Thanks for your time :)